# Google App-script Autosort on edit

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Ive been working on automatically sorting my data (ascending based on 2nd row 1st column data) and I found some tips through searching online but encountered an error which seems I cant find an answer through the net.

so heres the scenario:

I have 2 sheets, Sheet1 & Sheet2, the data from sheet1 is linked through sheet2 although sheet2 has additional columns,

this is sheet1

[image: Sheet1]

and this is sheet2

[image: Sheet2]

notice that the Column lastname and code in both sheets are thesame, the difference is the column Gender (Formatted on drop-down list) & Bdate(cell formatted as date)

I found a script that seems to work but I does not properly work completely, here is the output after I run the script.

[image]

notice the columns that inside the red box, it seems gender and bdate didnt follow the auto sort.

here is my code:

```
function autosortOnEdit() {
var sheetNames = ["Sheet1", "Sheet2"];
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
sheetNames.forEach(function(name) {
var sheet = ss.getSheetByName(name);
var range = sheet.getRange(2, 1, sheet.getLastRow() - 1, sheet.getLastColumn() -1);
range.sort({column: 1, ascending: true});
});
}
```

my observation is I think this script does not work on cells that are formatted like the example above.

I want to sort this automatically based on column A "last name".

how can i make this script work even on formatted cells?

Thanks in Advance, I will continue searching through the net.

Comment: Can you prepare sample sheet to test?

Comment: [link](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1_pHKo9rzkU_2p6GolvaD8j2z_hcZttu3bffzYykIHGM/edit?usp=sharing)  here is the sample sheet, I already added the script.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure how to use `range.sort({column: 1, ascending: true});` or how does it work, but whenever I want to sort sheet values, I do the following:

```
function myFunction() 
{
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  var rows = sheet.getLastRow();
  var columns = sheet.getLastColumn();

  var sortedValues = sheet.getRange(2, 1, rows-1, columns).getValues().sort();

  sheet.getRange(2, 1, rows-1, columns).setValues(sortedValues);
}
```

Try this instead of your code, hope this helps as it is successfully sorting all the values when I tested.

**EDIT**

To apply the same to all sheets inside a spreadsheet, you can get sheet names and iterate it in for loop one by one. Check the code:

```
function myFunction() 
{
  var sheets = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheets();
  var currentSheetName, currentSheet;

  for(var i=0; i<sheets.length; i++)
  {
    currentSheetName = sheets[i].getName();

    currentSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(currentSheetName);
    var rows = currentSheet.getLastRow();
    var columns = currentSheet.getLastColumn();

    var sortedValues = currentSheet.getRange(2, 1, rows-1, columns).getValues().sort();

    currentSheet.getRange(2, 1, rows-1, columns).setValues(sortedValues);
  }    
}
```

Comment: can this script be able to run on multiple sheets?

Comment: Yup, you can write like this `var sheets = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheets();` and then `  sheets[0].getName();` to get each and every sheet. Now just replace sheet1 with `sheets[i].getName()` variable. Let me know, if you want more clarification, I'll update the answer itself.

Comment: can you update your answer please? i cant seem to make it work, your answer is almost perfect, i just need it to run on multiple sheets, thanks

Comment: @user7254740 I have updated the answer, hope it is the exact solution which you were looking for. Check the edit section.